# Is there a way in python to show how a line is interpreted?

Tags: python

When running python there is an interpretation question based on

```
>>> 5 > 25 == False
False
>>> (5 > 25) == False
True
```

Since this was a question about order of operation, I would like to actually see how the python interpreter actually handles the two statements. Is there a method to do so?

Comment: It's not just order of operations. `5 > 25 == False` is distinct from both `(5 > 25) == False` and `5 > (25 == False)`. It is a shorthand for `(5 > 25) && (25 == False)`.

Comment: the dis module maybe?

Comment: You might want at [astdump](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astdump/3.3).

Comment: Is this like a homework question or something? Cause I saw 3 posts of the exact question (one got deleted, the other is the dup, and now this) within 2 hours of each other.... Or is the universe so align today.

Comment: @MooingRawr That question got me curious about attempting to actually see the interpreter parsing. In fact I used the code in that question as the example. While an answer to mine would allow someone to answer that question, I am interested in the general method rather than that answer itself.

Comment: @sabbahillel Ahh, my apology, I thought you were just simply rewording the same question.

Comment: @chepner I saw that answer in the original question. However, the use of ast in the answer explains the actual usage in the interpreter and that is what I wanted to learn. That question was just the simplest example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module can show an abstract syntax tree for an expression or statement:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('5 > 25 == False'))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(left=Num(n=5), ops=[Gt(), Eq()], comparators=[Num(n=25), NameConsta
nt(value=False)]))])'
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(5 > 25) == False'))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(left=Compare(left=Num(n=5), ops=[Gt()], comparators=[Num(n=25)]), o
ps=[Eq()], comparators=[NameConstant(value=False)]))])'
```

The [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module can show bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('5 > 25 == False')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (25)
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
             17 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   21 ROT_TWO
             22 POP_TOP
             23 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('(5 > 25) == False')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (25)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

`dis` can also operate on the the compiled bytecode stored in a function, and also as a standalone utility with `python3 -m dis`.

Passing a string to `dis.dis()` is new in Python 3; here are some equivalent ways to call this function:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 5 > 25 == False)
>>> dis.dis(compile('5 > 25 == False', '', 'eval'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html) module to parse your expression. The resulting parse tree should provide a clue as to how the expression will be evaluated.